# Replacing firmware, Longshine Shinebook

Tags: firmware, linux

Am wondering how to replace the firmware on a Longshine Shinebook ([manual](https://manual.longshine.de/4_GPL_Product_Driver/LCS-Shinebook/LCS-Shinebook_Manual.pdf), [firmware](https://manual.longshine.de/4_GPL_Product_Driver/LCS-Shinebook/LCS-Shinebook_Libre_Firmware.rar), [more stuff](https://manual.longshine.de/4_GPL_Product_Driver/LCS-Shinebook/LCS-Shinebook_Opensource.tgz)).

[image]

Assuming I modify the firmware files, how do I put the new version on the device? I'm guessing there is some standard method for triggering the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the firmware package, the `/etc/int.d/rcS` startup script has these lines at the end:

```
#for fs upgrade
#/bin/sd_upgrade_fs.sh
/bin/sd_upgrade_fs.sh
#for factory test
#sh /bin/mfg_test.sh
#/bin/watchdog.sh&
#/lib/modules/usb_mod
#exec /usr/etc/nanoX.local
```

And in `/bin/sd_upgrade_fs.sh` you can see how the initial firmware is written to the device. By looking up "eb600e" and "eb600em" present in `/files/`. I found [this old thread](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=60496) with some suggestions on how to trigger a firmware update process.